# How to calculate values for -- / ++

Tags: c, variables, assignment-operator, post-increment, pre-increment

I am trying to get the value for the last equation

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

a = b++ + ++c;
printf("a=%d\n", a);

x = y + 1 + ++z;
printf("x=%d\t", x);

printf("b=%d\t", --b);
printf("b=%d\t", b++);
printf("c=%d\t", c+1);
printf("c=%d\t", 2-c);
```

whats the value of the last equation and why? how do I calculate it

Comment: As for me then I have not understood what is the problem.

Comment: As ever, @Vlad, you're a few seconds ahead of me! Must be a time-zone issue?

Comment: What output did you get when you ran the code?

Answer (score 3):

These statements

```
printf("c=%d\t", c+1);
printf("c=%d\t", 2-c);
```

do not change the value of the variable `c`.

The variable was changed only in this statement

```
a = b++ + ++c;
          ^^^
```

If you want to change the variable `c` in the calls of printf then you should write at least

```
printf("c=%d\t", c = c+1);
printf("c=%d\t", c = 2-c);
```

Then the output will look like

```
a=1
x=2 b=0 b=0 c=2 c=0
                ^^^
```

Without these changes the output is

```
a=1
x=2 b=0 b=0 c=2 c=1 
                ^^^
```